# Issue in list() method of module boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am using the list method as:

```
all_keys = self.s3_bucket.list(self.s3_path)
```

The bucket "s3_path" contains files and folders. The return value of above line is confusing. It is returning:

1. Parent directory
2. A few directories not all
3. All the files in folder and subfolders.

I had assumed it would return files only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually no such thing as a **folder** in Amazon S3. It is just provided for convenience. Objects can be stored in a given path even if a folder with that path does not exist. The **Key** of the object is the full path plus the filename.

For example, this will copy a file even if the folder does not exist:

```
aws s3 cp file.txt s3://my-bucket/foo/bar/file.txt
```

This will not create the `/foo/bar` folder. It simply creates an object with a Key of: `/foo/bar/file.txt`

However, if folders are created in the S3 Management Console, a **zero-length file** is created with the name of the folder so that it appears in the console. When listing files, this **will appear** as the name of the directory, but it is actually the name of a zero-length file.

That is why some directories might appear but not others -- it depends whether they were specifically created, or whether they objects were simply stored in that path.

**Bottom line:** Amazon S3 is an object storage system. It is really just a big Key/Value store -- the Key is the name of the Object, the Value is the contents of the object. Do not assume it works the same as a traditional file system.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of items in the bucket, the results of a `list_objects` will be paginated. By default, it will return up to 1000 items. See the [Boto docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects) to learn how to use `Marker` to pagniate through all items.

Oh, looks like you're on Boto 2. For you, it will be [BucketListResultSet](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucketlistresultset.BucketListResultSet).